# Terraform - error: extra characters after interpolation expression

Tags: terraform, syntax-error, interpolation

When I add some data resource on my **Terraform** `aws_iam_policy_document` I'm getting some interpolation error:
*`Error: Extra characters after interpolation expression`*

That's the block of code:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "example_iam_policy_document" {

... // some statement
... // some other statement
... // some other statement
 
statement {
          actions   = [
              "ssm:TerminateSession"
          ]
          effect   = "Allow"
          resources = ["arn:aws:ssm:*:*:session/${aws:username}-*"]
      }
}
```

What's wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 7):

Modifying `${aws:username}` to `$${aws:username}`will fix the problem since terraform thinks `${aws:username}` is a variable and not an interpolation representation.

Comment: Coincidentally, (because someone else encountered a similar problem not long ago) the forthcoming v0.15.1 release of Terraform will include an extra hint in the error message for this situation that you need to escape the `${` if you intend it to be interpreted by something other than Terraform itself. [This particular data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document) also supports a special syntax `&{aws:username}` for this situation, but the effect is the same.